# Apache server not responding in ec2

Tags: apache, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a flask application hosted on ec2 ubuntu instance and to serve the http request i also have apache and wsgi configured. However i am not able to access my application in ec2 and the request is getting timed out everytime.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFPig.png)

Comment: check whether the apache is even running on the ec2 server. Run this command ```netsat -tlnp```

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation i found that apache is accepting request but i have used open cv in my code and the code functionality that uses open cv is taking a long amount of time.